# Java 7 http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/xmlSecurityPropertyManager

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Old code parsing XSD which worked with Java 6 fails with Java 7. Reason boils down to property http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/xmlSecurityPropertyManager not being set, which causes a NullPointerException. Code:

```
System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY, "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl");
    DOMImplementationRegistry registry = newInstance();
    XSImplementation impl = (XSImplementation) registry.getDOMImplementation("XS-Loader");
    XSLoader schemaLoader = impl.createXSLoader(null);

    String url = SchemaParser.class.getResource("/some.xsd").toURI().toString();

    XSModel model = schemaLoader.loadURI(url);
```

NPE happens inside loadUri, class XSDHandler.reset():

```
    XMLSecurityPropertyManager securityPropertyMgr = (XMLSecurityPropertyManager)
            componentManager.getProperty(XML_SECURITY_PROPERTY_MANAGER);
    //Passing on the setting to the parser
    fSchemaParser.setProperty(XML_SECURITY_PROPERTY_MANAGER, securityPropertyMgr);;
```

securityPropertyMgr, setProperty() throws NPE. How can I fix this?

Comment: Adding this solves the problem:  ((XSLoaderImpl)schemaLoader).setParameter("http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/xmlSecurityPropertyManager", new XMLSecurityPropertyManager());
Still have no idea why I should do this.

Answer (score 0):

They use an == comparison. I had to use the constant:

```
((XSLoaderImpl)loader).setParameter(
     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.Constants.XML_SECURITY_PROPERTY_MANAGER, 
     new XMLSecurityPropertyManager());
```

See: http://osdir.com/ml/core-libs-dev/2013-08/msg00260.html but it is for JDK 8, I hope we get a fix in 7 but I was unsuccessful in posting a bug for it.